# pandas dataframe multiline query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6, multiline

Say I have a dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

if I now try to query it using the `query` method:

this works:

`df.query('''a > 3  and b < 9''')`

this throws an error:

```
df.query(
    '''
        a > 3 and
        b < 9
    '''
)
```

I tried many variations of multiline strings but the result is always the following error:

```
~/ven/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py in eval(expr, parser, engine, truediv, local_dict, global_dict, resolvers, level, target, inplace)
    306     if multi_line and target is None:
    307         raise ValueError(
--> 308             "multi-line expressions are only valid in the "
    309             "context of data, use DataFrame.eval"
    310         )

ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval
```

Does anyone know how to make it work?
The problem is that in reality I have a very long query to do and it would be very inconvenient having to write all in one line.
I know I could use boolean indexing instead but my question is only about how to use multiline with the `query` method.

Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use multi-line char backslash ( `\` )

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(df.query(
    '''
        a > 3 and \
        b < 9
    '''
))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the new line character `\n` to allow multiline query

```py
query_multiline = '''
  a > 3 and
  b < 9
'''

query_multiline = query_multiline.replace('\n', '')

df.query(query_multiline)
```

Comment: For non-trivial, multi-line queries, **this solution is superior** (IMHO) to escaping the newlines with backslashes as shown in the other answer (with more up-votes currently). Two reasons: 1) it's tedious and error-prone to edit your existing query, escaping all the potentially many newlines, and 2) adding a slew of ` \ ` can obfuscate your nicely formatted multi-line query, possibly impacting maintenance. Save yourself the effort, keep your query nice-looking, and do it _programmatically_ with `query.replace('\n', '')`!