# Why do I need an explicit line break with this function?

Tags: python, pandas

This doesn't work:

```
df.query('`Record Type` == "Keyword" &
         `Campaign Status` == "enabled"')
```

But this does:

```
df.query('`Record Type` == "Keyword" & \
        `Campaign Status` == "enabled"')
```

There are times when I don't use a \ within the parentheses of a function and it seems to work, and other times it doens't, and I am not able to identify why. My understanding was that there could be line breaks without a \ if there are parentheses surrounding the statement, but obviously my understanding is incorrect...

Comment: Both statements should work just fine, and they work for me.  You can have embedded newlines inside any set of brackets (round, square, or curly).  If you're getting a syntax error, please post it.

Comment: Your linebreak is inside a `''` string literal, as indicated by the `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` that you should be getting.  If you want to do a multiline string literal, use `""""""`.  If you don't want the linebreak inside the string itself, end the string with a closing quote, and continue on the next line in a new string literal.

Comment: pandas does not support multi-line queries. @Samwise advice to use triple quotes won't help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597476/pandas-dataframe-multiline-query