# ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval even after backslash

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a multiline query using `df.query` but I seem to be getting the following error even after adding backslashes:

```
    column = 'method'

    idx = df.query(
    f"""{column} == 'One' and \
    number.notnull() and \
    flag.isnull()""").index
```

My df looks like this:

```
df
    'method'  'number'  'flag'
23   'One'    0         None
24   'One'    1         1
25   'Two'    1         None
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval
```

I tried to use this answer to fix but am still getting the exact same error:

[pandas dataframe multiline query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597476/pandas-dataframe-multiline-query)

Can someone help explain why this does not work?

Thanks

Comment: which pandas version do you use? I don't reproduce your issue on 1.5.2

Comment: 1.5.2 @mozway. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest avoiding `df.query`, it is easier and more reliable to use the masking feature to filter your data. The triple quotes are also taking the indentation characters, you should avoid that.

Now, in your case,

Better syntax, with string concatenation:

```py
column = 'method'

idx = df.query(
    f"{column} == 'One' and "
    "number_col.notnull() and "
    "flag.isnull()""").index"
)
```

A better solution, with filtering:

```py
column = "method"
mask = (df[column] == "One") & df["number"].notna() & df["flag"].isna()
idx = df[mask].index
```